# How to assign default value or preload data to Ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajaxform

I am creating a filter using checkbox and was able to do it. However, my problem is how I can I assign a default or preload loop without form submission to **#response**. Executing the script below would return a loop.
I am trying to learn ajax but in PHP the logic would be something like

```
    $response = 'myloop';

echo $response; // display the default loop

if ($search == 'true') {
    $response  = 'mynewloop'; // change the default loop
}
else {
    $response = 'myloop'; // return to default loop
}
```

this is my ajax jquery

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#filter').submit(function(){
        var filter = $('#filter');
        $.ajax({
            url:filter.attr('action'),
            data:filter.serialize(), // form data
            type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('button').text('Processing...'); // changing the button label
            },
            success:function(data){
                filter.find('button').text('Apply filter'); // changing the button label back
                $('#response').html(data); // insert data
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Really not clear what you need to accomplish here before the submit occurs. Tell us what the higher level problem is you need to solve

Comment: i simply want to load a loop in #response without any event being triggered. Currently, the loop will only be loaded if a trigger event happens. I wanted to show a standard loop first(showing everything) and when an event happens, that loop will change

Comment: In other words do same ajax request on page load? Still a bit vague

Comment: yes sir that is correct

Comment: So you could send something like `data:{pageload: true}` and check for `$_POST['pageload']` and send appropriate response

Comment: could you please provide a snippet as I am not to familiar with ajax script, would really appreciate it thanks in advance